# safely define Qt constants in a shell script

Tags: qt, build-automation

I have 6 versions of my application and I build then all every night.
My .pro file looks like that :

```
DEFINES += \
TEN_INCH \
#TG_MODULE \
NEW_DIALOG
```

Thus, so as to build the different version automatically, my shell script edits the .pro file, thanks to `sed`. This sucks because the defines must be on their own line, and Qt Creator sometimes put them all on the same (when adding a file for example). The result is that my build seems to work, but it isn't.

So, is there a better solution to do it ? Something like passing the defines to `qmake` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not edit your .pro file. Instead, use .pro file scopes:

```
build_one {
  DEFINES += whatever
}
build_two {
  DEFINES += something_else
}
```

And then activate them from qmake command line:

```
qmake CONFIG+=build_one && make clean && make
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, why don't you rewrite you script so it would form the whole DEFINES directive itself?

I.e. use sed to find existing one and replace it as a whole with newly formed one? In this case it wouldn't matter if it's on one line or spans several lines.

Comment: Unfortunately, I often need to comment/uncomment a define when I code. I definitively need them.